# Remove Application folder by uninstalling setup project

Tags: c#, wpf, setup-project

I have a wpf application and I have created setup project for that.

In my application some files and folders are getting created at runtime in the application folder

Now I want to delete those folders and files while I uninstall that application, In fact I want to delete the folder of application while uninstalling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With *Setup and Deployment* project you can add to your installed/uninstalled assembly new class that inherits from [`Installer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer(v=vs.110).aspx) class which allows you to override some methods executed as specific stages of install/uninstall process among which you have:

```
public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
   base.Uninstall(savedState);
   // Do uninstall stuff here...
}
```